# Persistent Couldn't match expected type ‘Key table’ with actual type Text

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

i don't know it this is really a problem for you but for me its a big problem.
i have a form created in html and one of the field there will hold the the list of city ( it is a select tag) so the value of the option contains the `city_id`

and in my post handler it will look like this:

```
 postPriceR :: Handler Html
 postPriceR = do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    city <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "city"
    amount <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "amount"
    runDB $ insert $ Prices city 100.0 now Nothing
    redirect PriceR
```

this also will help you: 
My Models:

```
Prices
    cityId CitiesId
    amount Double
    createdOn UTCTime default=now()
    updatedOn UTCTime Maybe
    deriving Show Generic
Cities
    stateId StatesId
    name Text
    createdOn UTCTime default=now()
    updatedOn UTCTime Maybe
    deriving Show Generic
```

and give me this warning:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Key Cities’ with actual type Text …
```

hope you help me. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that `persistent` does not know how to translate a `Text` into your database key - assuming you got some kind of SQL store the usual solution is to use [`toSqlKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:toSqlKey)

Comment: @BitTickler look that is just OT here - if you have issues with the naming of functions in yesod you should go to their github page and open an issue there - here you are just *trolling*

Comment: @CarstenKönig - can you provide me a snippet? thank you

Comment: it's a bit tricky because I cannot compile/check your code - but instead `city` in `runDB $ insert $ Prices city ...` you should be able to use `city'` as in `let city' = toSqlKey . read . unpack $ city` - you probably need to import `toSqlKey` and `unpack`

Comment: or better use a `intField` then you can remove the `read . unpack` stuff!

Comment: @CarstenKönig - it works i just add some code that you gave to me.

Comment: glad I could help - of course you might want to use the more involved `selectFieldList` to but I'm sure you'll get it. - Shall I add it as an answer (meaning: is the comment acceptable for you)?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this using @CarstenKönig help. using the [`toSqlKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:toSqlKey)

here it is:

`import Data.Int`

```
runDB $ insert $ Prices (toSqlKey (read (unpack city) :: Int64 ) ) 100.0 now Nothing
```

thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: or so ;) - fine with me